# Is There Techniques for creating synthetic Data for Regression Problem i tried SMOTE and its variant but these are for classification problem

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, regression, data-cleaning, data-augmentation

[image]

This is my data "Volume" is my Target variable and all other are Independent variables i just applied labelencoder on Area_categ , wind_direction_labelencod and on current _label_encode and now i want to apply tecnique that increase my dataset rows and colums like in case of classification SMOTE do balance classes.Please give me solution for this if possible with deep learing  techniques then please do help us.

Comment: Why do you feel the need to synthesize fictional data?

Comment: hello Dave. thanks to hear this
in my case i just want to increase the size of dataset not privacy or confidentiality matter. will this work https://pypi.org/project/smogn/ for me ?